# Java quick string matching (to associate a text to a category)

Tags: java, string, string-matching

Suppose i have a post which is something like

- TITLE: "WEB: SEO in 2011"
- DESCRIPTION: "A conference talking about SEO in the web of the 2011"

also, i have a list of categories with keywords associated:

- "IT" (cat) -> "Web design", "seo", "developing", "web developing" (keywords)

i have multiple categories (it, arts, medicals, literature, machinery etc...)

i need to use java to automatically upgrade my posts with those categories and keywords (a sort of tagging) to improve future searching.

The example above: should match "seo" and "web" so the main_category field should be filled up with "IT" and the subfield_category should be filled up with "seo" or "web" (or maybe both, which isn't bad too)

my problem is that the only solution i can come up with is waaaaay into the bruteforcing (test all the words, when one matches you have the category and the list of the keywords associated with it) and it will slower my performances...

is there any way i can do the search in a better way? also i can modify my category->keywords structure to do something better (i still don't know how...)

thanks all in advance!

EDIT: accuracy isn't so much important, as amit asked in a comment. i don't need 100% accuracy on tagging, since i know i can have an honest amount of correctness based on raw matching of the strings.

Also, the logic i was thinkinking about is: look at post title/description, search for any keywords matching, tag with category, search for more keywords into this category, save 3 to 5 matching keywords

Comment: do you have a sample for learning? [i.e. a set of documents you know how they should be tagged]?

Comment: also, are you intrested in accuracy of tagging? or can you assume the tag-word is in always in the topic/description?

Comment: well this is the biggest problem: nope :( i just have the raw documents, without any sample context :( accuracy is not important, that's why i've decided to associate 2-3 second-level keywords to each post

Comment: Do you need to find a category by word in text and then associated that word with set of words corresponding to found category?

Comment: More or less: i'll search for a keyword first of all, since a general category is harder to spot (i cannot associate "web" to "it" based on raw string match... i should first of all search for a keyword matching, or similar, to web, then extract the category)

Comment: If I understand you correctly the main category is derived from words in the post (title, description, text). What if the post would contain keywords that would put it into 2 categories (e.g. "it" and "arts") - which one should be taken then?

Comment: Maybe some kind of voting algorithm?

Comment: Thomas: keywords are provided by our seo "experts" and no keywords are cross category.. but, anyway, the idea is to match the category which contains the biggest number of keywords (we're supposing our post are well writteng... we're hoping, at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a different approach, using [Machine Learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning).

**Algorithm Description:**

First, create a learning samples [documents you know for sure how they should be tagged, you can tag a sample manually and give it as input to the algorithm]. Then, create [Bag Of Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) for these samples, using `k` bag of words [you will need to decide which `k` is optimal, by benchmarking the quality, I'll explain later on].

Every word is a 'feature', and next, for each new document, you will try to find which document from the learning sample is the [nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) [i.e. has most 'words' in common in your Bag Of Words], the new document will be tagged as its nearest neighbor.

**How to Benchmark Quality?**

you can check for quality by taking 10% documents out of the learning sample, and learn only on the remaining 90%. after done learning, you can evaluate how accurate your algorithm is by checking the accuracy of the remaining 10%. Note that you will probably need to do this a few times to find optimal k [Bag Of Words size] as mentioned above.

Comment: should k be equal for every bag i have? all the keywords i have are provided by some SEO experts or whatever, and the lists are very different (for some categories i have something like 20 keywords, others have just 2-3) also: i know the learning samples are, well, fundamental in this approach, but do you think it will be possible to implement an hybrid solution? i think i know the answer, since ml is impossible without a learning base, right?

Comment: you must have a learning sample. however,this approach do not require deciding which words are the key words, they will be chosen by the BoW . I think it worths trying,had pretty good results when I used it to find positiveness of tweets a few months ago

Comment: i'll give it a try, i have to plan it very carefully, it's a blocking issue (cannot go online without categorization) but i cannot also spend too much time on it... i'll leave this question open for other suggestions, but i'm trying yours (and if its the only one, i'll accept it in 2-3 days, promise!)

Comment: based on your answer i found this http://classifier4j.sourceforge.net/ which is perfect, using the Bayesian classifier combined with the bag of words approach it works smoothly, i can rate the matches and add the correct values with an high percentage of accuracy! thanks for the idea amit!